# Django's custom template tag deletes HTML content

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I've created a custom tag to hide zero values from HTML. I use this for hiding currency formatted numbers when its values are zero.

This is my custom tag:

```
def hideifz(value):
    return '' if value == 0 else value
```

The problem is that this tag deletes some of my HTML.

This is the relevant part of my template:

```
<div class="price">
    <span class="price-new">{{ publication.price_record.low_price|CLP }}</span>
    <span class="price-old">{{ publication.price_record.high_price|hideifz|CLP }}</span>
</div>
```

This HTML is for showing product prices. `publication.price_record.low_price` and `publication.price_record.high_price`are the prices of my product. If the product is in sale, it must have `high_price != 0`, and this value must be shown in the HTML.

CLP is just another tag for currency formatting:

```
def toCLP(value):
    if not value:
        return value
    return '$'+intcomma(int(value)).replace(',', '.')
```

If `high_price` is not zero, the output HTML is okay. For example:

```
<div class="price">
    <span class="price-new">$75.990</span>
    <span class="price-old">$83.990</span>
</div>
```

In the other hand, if `high_price` is zero, some of my HTML is deleted:

```
<div class="price">$21.990</div>
```

Note that `span.price-new` and `span.price-old` were removed.

Now, if I remove the `hideifz` tag, the output of the previous example looks like this:

```
<div class="price">
    <span class="price-new">$21.990</span>
    <span class="price-old">0.0</span>
</div>
```

The spans are back when I remove the `hideifz` tag.

I just want to hide the python variable/value from the html, preserving the outer span for other uses.

I know I can solve this by simply using the `{% if val %}` tag, but I wanted to create my own tag for simplicty.

I'm working with django 1.10.

Thanks you.